# NSolve either produces wrong result or never stops (Solve does the job though) in Mathematica 10.x

Tags: equation-solving

I have a simple equation (if you are interested it is originated from the field of hydrology):

```
S^0.5 (1-(1-S^6)^0.166667)^2 == 1/1000
```

with `S` certainly being between 0 and 1. The LHS of the equation is strictly growing function of `S`. So, the equation can be solved numerically using bisection method (in fact, since the function grows very fast when `S->1`, something like *regula falsi* performs worse). In any case, there is strictly one solution (provided RHS is less then 1).

If I solve it with `Solve`, I get the correct result but with some warnings:

```
Solve[Sqrt[S] (1 - (1 - S^6)^0.166667)^2/1200 == 1/1200000, S, Reals]

Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

{{S -> 0.756191}}
```

I am guessing it solves it numerically. But if I try `NSolve`:

```
NSolve[S^0.5 (1 - (1 - S^6)^0.166667)^2 == 1/1000, S, Reals]
```

it never stops. Even more peculiar, if I set up the equation in a more systematic way (but with slightly perturbed exponent due to rounding error):

```
Kr[VanGenuchten[\[ScriptL]_, \[Alpha]_, n_], s_] := Block[{m},
  m = 1 - 1/n;
  s^\[ScriptL] (1 - (1 - s^(1/m))^m)^2]

Block[{m, s, \[ScriptL], \[Alpha], n, z, V, s0, k, S, eq},
 \[ScriptL] = 1/2;
 \[Alpha] = 3;
 n := 1.2;
 m = VanGenuchten[\[ScriptL], \[Alpha], n];
 V = 3/1000/3600;
 k = 3000/1000/3600;
 eq = k Kr[m, S] == V;
 Print[eq];
 NSolve[eq, S, Reals]]
```

It produces the erroneous result:

```
{{S -> -1.02481*10^-10}, {S -> 6.25*10^-8}}
```

without any warning.

I've browsed through potential pitfalls with `Solve` and `NSolve` and yet I couldn't put my finger on what the problem is here. I've tried to use `Rationalize`, setting higher precision and adding extra inequalities `S>0 && S<1` to the equation, but to no avail.

PS. I am using Mathematica 10.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot confirm this behavior on Mathematica 11.0.1. In any case, I obtain `0.756191` as the only solution. This might have been fixed with Mathematica 11.

Comment: Use: `FindInstance[S^0.5 (1 - (1 - S^6)^0.166667)^2 == 1/1000, S, Reals]` is better than `NSolve`.

Comment: Solving the exact equation and applying `N`: `N@Solve[Sqrt[S] (1 - (1 - S^6)^(1/6))^2 == 1/1000, S, Reals]`,  gives `S -> 0.756191` with no errors. Using `NSolve` on the exact equation: `NSolve[Sqrt[S] (1 - (1 - S^6)^(1/6))^2 == 1/1000, S, Reals]` gives `S -> 4.3523*10^-8`. (MMA 10.4)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It does seem like a bug in version 10, tested on 10.2 - the same problem.

Comment: `NSolve` will rationalize the exponents and maybe it is getting `1666667/10000000` rather than 1/6. That would account for hanging. Upshot: don't use approximate values in exponents within `NSolve`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau it is a good point, but in my version of Mathematica, `NSolve` still returns `{}` with `1/6` in exponent, while `Solve` produces a correct result.

Comment: In 11.1: `In[151]:= NSolve[S^0.5 (1 - (1 - S^6)^(1/6))^2 == 1/1000, S, Reals]

Out[151]= {{S -> 0.756191167023}}` So maybe a problem got resolved?

Answer (score 1):

[`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) the equation

```
eqn1 = Sqrt[S] (1 - (1 - S^6)^0.166667)^2/1200 == 1/1200000 // Rationalize // 
  Simplify

(*  1000 Sqrt[S] (-1 + (1 - S^6)^(166667/1000000))^2 == 1  *)

Solve[eqn1, S, Reals]

(*  {{S -> Root[{-1 + 1000 #1 - 2000 #1 (1 - #1^12)^(166667/1000000) + 
       1000 #1 (1 - #1^12)^(166667/500000) &, 0.86959240365045343337}]^2}}  *)
```

The numeric approximation for this [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) object is

```
% // N

(*  {{S -> 0.756191}}  *)
```

This is the same result as from [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
NSolve[eqn1, S, Reals]

(*  {{S -> 0.756191}}  *)
```

**EDIT:** For the rationalized equation, Version 10 wortks if you specify the domain as [`Rationals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationals.html)

```
$Version

(*  "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"  *)

eqn1 = Sqrt[S] (1 - (1 - S^6)^0.166667)^2/1200 == 1/1200000 // Rationalize // 
  Simplify

(*  1000 Sqrt[S] (-1 + (1 - S^6)^(166667/1000000))^2 == 1  *)

NSolve[eqn1, S, Rationals] // Normal

(*  {{S -> Root[{-1 + 1000 #1 - 2000 #1 (1 - #1^12)^(166667/1000000) + 
       1000 #1 (1 - #1^12)^(166667/500000) &, 0.86959240365045343337}]^2}}  *)

% // N

(*  {{S -> 0.756191}}  *)
```

Comment: In theory it should work, but the problem seems to be a bug with `NSolve` in Mathematica 10.x, because if I copy-paste the code above, `NSolve` never stops.

Answer (score 1):

In short, Mathematica with version < 10.4 has a bug that seems to be fixed in Mathematica 11. (See comment by @HenrikSchumacher).

Some lessons learnt from this example:

1. Avoid floating point numbers in `NSolve`, especially in exponents: counter-intuitive, isn't it?
2. Prefer `FindInstance` to `NSolve`.
3. Before using `NSolve` do manual `Rationalize` on the equation to see if some numbers (especially exponents) are not rationalizing well.

If anyone would like to comment on it, please do. Especially, I am quite intrigued by the fact that `NSolve` that has `N` in it doesn't do well with floating point numbers.

Comment: To be clear, what `NSolve` does not handle well are floating point exponents. Given the ref page bullet item "NSolve deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations", and the fact that it attempts to find all solutions, this should not be surprising.